# VBA for MicroStation - defining a position about an angle

Tags: vba

This is more a maths conundrum than specifically coding but I'm sure I'll need help there too.

I am writing some code to place a MicroStation cell at a chosen scale and then to use MicroStation commands to stretch part of the cell to another location. The coding was complete, I thought, as it worked in my test environment but in testing with some users it broke immediately. It took some time to establish the reason and it is caused by the on screen view having a rotation applied.

My code relies on capturing the user placed position for the start of the cell placement retrieved using a point3d, I then need to select another point at a set distance along XY from the last point, this is adjusted by factoring in the chosen scale "CellScale as integer" so my second position is defined as:

```
PosFlood.X=Pos1.X + (0.35 * CellScale)
PosFlood.Y=Pos1.Y + (0.007 * CellScale)
```

But this calculation is wrong when the view is rotated. I have been able to retrieve the rotation angle and set it as "ViewAngle as Double" but I don't know what formula to use to calculate my second position, I believe I need to use sin and cos but all searching has brought me up short.

Hopefully there is a maths wizard out in cyber space who can put me on the right path?

Thanks - Mark

Answer (score 0):

MicroStation is 3D, and using angles is not good way to deal with rotation.  A common approach in 3D math is to use a *rotation matrix*, which is fully supported by MicroStation VBA with the `Matrix3D` class.

You can get the rotation matrix of a MicroStation view using `View.Rotation`.  You will find many methods that operate on a `Matrix3D` in MicroStation VBA help.  Those methods include calculating a scaling matrix and multiplying matrices (e.g. `scaling matrix . rotation matrix`) to obtain a rotation for your cell.